# How to create a JSON with different datatype?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net, serialization

I'm making a JSON which is serialized from this object:

```
}).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new
{
    ID = p.ID,
    ClinicID = p.Clinic.ID,
    MedicalID = p.Medical.ID,
    PatientID = p.Patient.ID,
    TreatmentTypeID = p.TreatmentType.ID,
    ActivityStatusID = p.ActivityStatusID,
    Estimate = p.Estimate
}).ToList();
```

all values have type `int`, except `Estimate` which is `decimal`.
I'd like to create a JSON as "array of elements" instead of a object with name/value pair.

But I can't do:

```
}).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new List<int>()
{
    p.ID,
    p.Clinic.ID,
    p.Medical.ID,
    p.Patient.ID,
    p.TreatmentType.ID,
    p.ActivityStatusID,
    p.Estimate
}).ToList();
```

since `Estimate` has different data type. How can I do it?

Can I simple "flat" values serializing on JSON?

```
return Json(new { data = data, recordsFiltered = data.Count, recordsTotal = data.Count });
```

Comment: Which serializer are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `List<int>` to `List<object>`

```
}).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new List<object>()
{
    p.ID,
    p.Clinic.ID,
    p.Medical.ID,
    p.Patient.ID,
    p.TreatmentType.ID,
    p.ActivityStatusID,
    p.Estimate
}).ToList();
```